# Rename Marketplace tag to Store

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently the Store tag is an alias of Marketplace. It should be the other way!

Answer (score 3):

Agreed.

When merge tags is not so obvious which one will be the master. Probably someone just merge them and didn't realized that it had been changed.

Comment: ...and now done